# Detecting whitespaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, string, nsstring

How do I detect whitespaces in objective-c? I've tried this:

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:@" ") {
// Log it
NSLog(@"match");
}
```

but it doesn't fire, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by:

```
if ([myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {

    NSLog(@"Whitespace found");

} else {

    NSLog(@"Whitespace not found");
}
```

Instead of `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]` you can use `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]` to detect newline too.

**Apple's documentation** says `whitespace` includes `space` and `tab`

> A character set containing only the in-line whitespace characters
>   space (U+0020) and tab (U+0009).

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
if([myString rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound)
{
     NSLog(@"match");           
}
```

Comment: Both answers were very good :) - thanks! (Don't got the reputation required to vote up :/)